# Taking certain column values from one row in a Pandas Dataframe and adding them into another dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I would like to copy certain column values from a specific row in my dataframe `df` to another dataframe called `bestdf`

Here I create an empty dataframe (called `bestdf`):

```
new_columns = ['DATE', 'PRICE1', 'PRICE2']
bestdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = new_columns)
bestdf.set_index(['DATE'])
```

.I've located a certain row out of `df` and assigned the row to a variable `last_time`:

```
last_time = df.iloc[-1]
print last_time
```

gives me

```
                  DATETIME     PRC
2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000  335.82
```

I  then want to take the `2016-10-03` from the `DATETIME` column and put that into the `DATE` column of my other dataframe (`bestdf`).
I also want to take the `PRC` and put it into the `PRICE1` column of my empty dataframe. I want `bestdf` to look like this:

```
                      DATE  PRICE1  PRICE2
                2016-10-03  335.82
```

Here is what I've got so far?

```
sample_date = str(last_time).split()
best_price = sample_date[2]
sample_date = sample_date[0]

bestdf['DATE'] = sample_date
bestdf['PRICE1'] = best_price
```

This doesn't seem to work though. FYI I also want to put this into a loop (where last_time will be amended and each time the new values will be written to a new row). I'm just currently trying to get the functionality correct.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a minimal example and show your desired output?!

Comment: do you want to create a new dataframe from certain rows and columns of another dataframe ?

Comment: @VikashSingh thats what I want to do yes (I've edited the above to make it more informative).

Comment: @Cleb please see above edits, thanks

Comment: @nrs90 if you can share your source dataFrame structure also it would be of much help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do what are you are looking to do:
Also you can break your problem down into multiple pieces. That way you will be able to apply different steps to solve them.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = [{'DATETIME': '2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000', 'PRC': 335.29},
        {'DATETIME': '2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000', 'PRC': 33.9},
        {'DATETIME': '2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000', 'PRC': 10.9}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')

df
```

output:

```
    DATETIME                    PRC
0   2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000  335.29
1   2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000  33.90
2   2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000  10.90
```

code continue:

```
bestdf = df[df['PRC'] > 15].copy()
# we filter data from original df and make a copy
bestdf.columns = ['DATE','PRICE1']
# we change columns as we need
bestdf['PRICE2'] = None
bestdf
```

output:

```
    DATE                        PRICE1  PRICE2
0   2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000  335.29  None
1   2016-10-03 00:07:39.295000  33.90   None
```

code continue:

```
bestdf['DATE'] = bestdf['DATE'].apply(lambda value: value.split(' ')[0])
# we change column format based on how we need it to be
bestdf
```

output:

```
    DATE    PRICE1  PRICE2
0   2016-10-03  335.29  None
1   2016-10-03  33.90   None
```

We can also do the same thing with datetime objects also. Doesn't have to be string necessarily.